# TCP server (Python) on Raspberry Pi bootup results in error: Address already in use

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, boot, tcpserver

I have a TCP server created on a Python script, I want to execute it on Raspberry Pi boot up. I have put the Python script in .bashrc and it executes on the boot up, but it displays the following error:

> s.bind(('', 5555))
>   socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use

I have created a TCP client on Matlab and the communciation works perfectly. I can manually execute the server from Raspberry Pi 3 command line send/recv data and close the socket, but even after properly closing if I restart my Raspberry Pi, on boot up it still displays the error.

I have also tried  `s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)`, but I still get the error. I dont want to manually change the port number every time, therefore any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is this tagged with MATLAB? Is that really relevant? Are you addressing MATLAB experts?

Comment: Have you tried with a different port number?

Comment: @AndrasDeak the TCP client is hosted on Matlab, but yeah ur right its not directly related to Matlab

Comment: @dhdavvie Yes, I have that works but I dont want to change the port number every time manually

Answer (score 1):

This message occurs when you try to use a port number that is already in use.

Because you start the server process with your `.bashrc` file, an attempt will be made to start it when your system boots, when you start a new shell, or when you `ssh` into the system.

[This article](https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/run-a-program-on-your-raspberry-pi-at-startup/) makes some suggestions about other ways you could use.

Note that when you see this message, it comes from repeated attempts to start your server, but the good news is you should still be able to connect to the server - the message does imply it's already running.

Comment: So I dont know if I completely understood ur comment, is it that when Raspberry Pi is powered up it tries to repeatedly start the server and when I try to SSH into Rspberry Pi, it shows the error? Even if thats the case the control is returned back to the command line and I cannot connect the client  to my server. sorry if I am making no sense

Comment: The problem is that your network might not be up yet. You should either run your script delayed or start it as a service depending on the network service.

Comment: The message implies that more than one attempt is being made to start your server: "Address already in use" means something is already listening on that port. Consider, therefore, under what conditions command from the `.bashrc` file are run.